# The best source for reference information on Java interop with jRuby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, jruby-java-interop

What have you found as the best sources for jRuby interop syntax with Java? It took me forever yesterday to find something about adding to the classpath and the jruby.org site was not much help. Curious what references others use. Thanks.

Comment: also, pragmatic programmer (pragprog.com) has a beta book from several of the core contributors. I bought that book and its really work the investment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a page into the wiki with useful information about:

http://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Comment: David, thanks for the help on the jruby project, and great slides. I will probably be looking at them a few times today :)

Comment: @David your slides link is no longer accessible and has been removed. Please update your answer with up to date link if it is still available elsewhere. I couldn't find it. Thanks